# Problems With SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

Currently having problems trying to implement an updater Trigger for my SQL table where changing discounts(by percentage) will always be update the final price of the item.

This is the problem I am facing and I am unsure why:

> > #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

For example, Item A's price would be 100 with a discount of 25(%). This means that the cost of Item A would be 75

Any changes to discount like say, 25 to 0 OR 25 to 50, would lead to prices like 100 and 50 respectively

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DiscountUpdate BEFORE UPDATE ON game
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF NEW.Discount <> OLD.Discount THEN
      BEGIN
           SET NEW.NetPrice=NEW.BaseGamePrice-(NEW.BaseGamePrice*(NEW.Discount/100));
      END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two BEGIN, remove `BEGIN` after `if.. then`
Also, you missed `UPDATE`  statement before `SET` clause. Add `UPDATE tablename..` after the `if.. then`. Try below

```
CREATE TRIGGER DiscountUpdate BEFORE 
UPDATE ON game
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.Discount <> OLD.Discount THEN
       Update Game 
       SET NEW.NetPrice=NEW.BaseGamePrice- 
       (NEW.BaseGamePrice*(NEW.Discount/100));
  END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: This error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Still appears